# Why same <p>tag id is firing when click on single p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use several `<p>` tags, all with same `id` attributes, for multiple purpose using jquery. but when i click on any one then jquery work for every `<p>` tag. how i will solve it.

```
<p id="inCom">Comment</p>
```

i want to use this `<p>` for multi time with same id and onclick its shows me a input div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).delegate("#inCom","click",function(e){
                $( "p" ).addClass( "clickme" );
                if($( "#inCom" ).hasClass( "clickme" )){
                    $('.comDiv').show();
                }

            });

        });
</script>

<div class="comDiv">
    <div class="comimg">
         <img src="images/placeholder_icon.png" alt="avatar" width="50px" height="50px">  
     </div>
     <div class="combody">
        <form id="comForm">
            <input type="text" name="comment"class="input" id="comment" placeholder="Type your comment" size="50" />
             <input type="submit" class="combtn" id="comsubmit" value="Post">
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs MUST be unique on document context. Now i'm not sure i understand your issue, if is it

Comment: Also, As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method

Comment: ID must be a uniuqe and class can be common

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your issue but IDs must be unique. Could u explain some more about what u wanna do?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do. Instead if id use class for the `<p>` tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inCom').on('click',function(e){
        $( "p" ).addClass( "clickme" );
        if($( "#inCom" ).hasClass( "clickme" )){
            $('.comDiv').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You aren't delegating event here, maybe OP needs it or not, unclear question IMHO

Comment: @DipokChakraborty Improve your question by providing relevant example replicating your issue

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) ID must be document-wide unique. Multiple HTML element having same 'id' is not the correct HTML standard.

Try use same class for different HTML elements and bind click event to class selector.